# React: Toggle content in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm stuck in this problem. I have a toggle component that is rendering a button to show/hide data aswell as the data that is being rendered.

**I want to separate both the button and the data so I can display the content in another component, and being able to hide it and show it from the toggle component, if it makes sense.**

Here is a picture to demonstrate what I'm wishing to do.

[Toggle Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gb6MF.jpg)

The **toggleComponent.js** that contains the button and the data :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class toggleComponent extends React.Component{
        constructor(){
            super();
            this.state={
                isShowBody: false
            } 
        }
    
        handleClick = (event) => {
            this.setState({ isShowBody: !this.state.isShowBody })
        }
    
        checkbox = () => {
            return (
                <div  >
                <span className="switch switch-sm" >
                              <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="select" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}/>
                                <span />
                              </label>
                            </span> 
                </div>
            )
        }
    
        content = () => {
            return (
                <div>
                    Displaying text
                </div>
            )
        }
    
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    {this.checkbox()}
                    {this.state.isShowBody && this.content ()}                    
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make another component named `content.js`. `Import` `ContentComponent` inside `ToggleComponent` and render it using `flag`.

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vied7p?file=src%2FApp.js)

### Solution:

**Toggle Component**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ContentComponent from "./content.js";

export default class toggleComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isShowBody: false
    };
  }

  handleClick = event => {
    this.setState({ isShowBody: !this.state.isShowBody });
  };

  checkbox = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <span className="switch switch-sm">
          <label>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name="select"
              onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
            />
            <span />
          </label>
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  };        

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.checkbox()}
        {this.state.isShowBody && <ContentComponent />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Content Component**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class ContentComponent extends React.Component {
  content = () => {
    return <div>Displaying text</div>;
  };

  render() {
    return <div>{this.content()}</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: You wouldn't believe how much I struggled for this. I created another .js and used a render function to pass data and nothing worked. Thank you very much man! I really need to know what to search because as a beginner I'm so lost in tutorials. Anyway thank you !

Comment: All pleasure @AlyaKra , Just approve this answer if it helped you! Yes, searching is more important part. One suggestion: read the official react doc, and read more articles. It will help you a lot. Thanks!!

Comment: I was waiting for a cooldown to approve the answer. Thank you.